# what is the equelent of sql query in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

In SQL Server i am using this query

```
select * 
from Unit c 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, LEFT(name, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', name + 'z')-1)) desc;
```

I want this query to use in Hibernate. when I use this in Hibernate I got error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:unexpected token: LEFT near line 1, column 122 
    [SELECT c FROM models.entities.UnitEntity c WHERE c.expSetId = :expSetId AND isWaitArea=:isWaitArea ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, LEFT(name, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', name + 'z')-1)) asc]
```

Comment: thx for helping in formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some of that is not in the hibernate dialect, you can change `left` with `substring`, `convert` with `cast`. and as for `patindex` i couldn't find the substitution. you either can add pathindex to the constructor of the dialect that you use

```
registerFunction( "patindex", new StandardSQLFunction("patindex") );
```

or create patindex() to a stored procedure.

then you can use something like this:

```
from Unit c order by cast(substring(name, 0, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', name + 'z')-1) as integer);
```

or you can use `locate()` instead of `patindex()`, but i think it doesn't support regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you can use SQL query with hibernate as well. When you create your hibernate session, you can use something like

```
session.createSQLQuery("Your Query Here")
```

Hope this helps.